# Expected depth of modified kind of treap

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, search-trees, heaps

If we have $n$ elements $s_1, \dots, s_n$ and build a kind of treap (tree-heap) out of it. Each $s_k$ has a priority, which is an integer in $\{ 1, 2, 3 \dots, \lceil \log n \rceil\}$. Since the priorities will have duplicates, I just want the treap the verify that for each node $s_k$, all the nodes in its right and left subtrees have smaller priority.

Is there a way to find the expected depth of this tree?

Comment: Is there any randomisation left? What is your input model? Why do you think performance differs from regular treaps?

Comment: I don't think the problem is well formed yet.  If two nodes have the highest priority then which one is the root?  Maybe the heap invariant is "smaller or equal" rather than "smaller?" Once you've solved that problem, then I think the distribution on the priorities needs to be geometric (1/2 the nodes have the lowest priority $\lceil \log n \rceil$, and only about $1/n$ of the nodes have highest priority $1$.) At that point you may be able to prove that the priority of each node is approximately its depth in the tree.

Comment: I think that either Martinez and Roura's Randomized Binary Search Tree paper or more likely Pugh's Skip Lists paper discusses assigning priorities based on such a geometric distribution.

Comment: I just know that the proofs you can find in books often suppose priorities are all different. This is no different from a regular treap but it's a treap that accepts equal priorities. So for each $s_i$, all elements $s_j$ in the subtrees verify $priority(s_j) \leq priority(s_i)$ instead of the former convenient $priority(s_j) < priority(s_i)$

Comment: to answer @WanderingLogic: the problem as it is leaves the possiblity of having multiple configurations for the same set of priorities & keys. But the thing is: the order of the keys is not random, so if the order happen to be very bad, and the priorities keep being redundant, we end up with a very unbalanced tree.

Comment: @helenatreder: That's why you either need $O(n)$ priorities that are uniformly distributed or $O(\log n)$ priorities that are geometrically distributed.  With a geometric distribution about half the nodes have the lowest priority, a quarter have the next lowest priority, ..., and about one node has the highest priority.  With $O(n)$ uniformly distributed priorities the priority with the most duplicates is expected to have something like $O(\log n / \log \log n)$ duplicates.

Comment: @WanderingLogic: ok, is there a way I can formally prove it's impossible?

Comment: Prove what is impossible?  I think it _is_ possible to have a tree with expected height $O(\log n)$ with duplicate priorities, as long as the priorities are chosen either uniformly distributed from the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$ or geometrically distributed from the set $\{ 1, \dots, \lceil \log n \rceil\}$.  (In fact the [wikipedia page on Treaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) gives the definition of treaps with possibly repeating priorities chosen uniformly from the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$.)